# Expected value of $E[X_n]$

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution

I have the following problem:

> Suppose that a point $X_1$ is chosen from a uniform distribution on
>   the interval $[0, 1]$, and that after the value $X_1=x_1$ is observed,
>   a point $X_2$ is chosen from a uniform distribution on $[x_1, 1]$. The
>   variables $X_3, X_4,\ldots$ are generated in the same way. In general,
>   for $j=1, 2,\ldots$, after $X_j=x_j$ is observed, $X_{j+1}$ s chosen
>   from a uniform distribution on $[x_j, 1]$. Calculate $E[X_n]$.

So, I get the the probability for $X_n$ to be equal to some value $a\in [x_{n-1}, 1]$ is $\dfrac{1}{1-x_n}$, given that $X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2,\ldots X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}$. But I don't really know how to continue to get the expected value from here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{1-x_n}$ is a density rather than a probability

Answer (score 4):

Hint :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X_n] &= \mathbb E[\mathbb E[X_n|X_{n-1}]]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[ \frac{1+X_{n-1}}{2} \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\mathbb E[X_{n-1}]}{2}
\end{align*}